# WPF application doesn't translate from the Resource Dictionary?

Tags: wpf

I am trying to create test multi language WPF using the method below, but when I run my application I only get only english translation while the date is being translated according to the specified language, while it ignore the spanish resource dictionary, I think the problem is in merged dictionaries. I want to solve the problem using the same method.

StringResources.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
<system:String x:Key="UserID">User ID</system:String>
<system:String x:Key="UserPassword">User Password</system:String>
<system:String x:Key="Login">Login</system:String>

 </ResourceDictionary>
```

StringResources.es-ES.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

<system:String x:Key="UserID">ID de usuario</system:String>
<system:String x:Key="UserPassword">usuario Contraseña</system:String>
<system:String x:Key="Login">Iniciar Sesión</system:String>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

App.xaml

```
  <Application x:Class="WpfStringTables.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
     <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary >
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/StringResources.es-ES.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/StringResources.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

App.xaml.cs

```
   public static void SelectCulture(string culture)
    {
        // List all our resources      
        List<ResourceDictionary> dictionaryList = new List<ResourceDictionary>();
        foreach (ResourceDictionary dictionary in Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries)
        {
            dictionaryList.Add(dictionary);
        }
        // We want our specific culture      
        string requestedCulture = string.Format("StringResources.{0}.xaml", culture);
        ResourceDictionary resourceDictionary = dictionaryList.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Source.OriginalString == requestedCulture);
        if (resourceDictionary == null)
        {
            // If not found, we select our default language        
            //        
            requestedCulture = "StringResources.xaml";
            resourceDictionary = dictionaryList.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Source.OriginalString == requestedCulture);
        }

        // If we have the requested resource, remove it from the list and place at the end.\      
        // Then this language will be our string table to use.      
        if (resourceDictionary != null)
        {
            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Remove(resourceDictionary);
            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(resourceDictionary);
        }
        // Inform the threads of the new culture      
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(culture);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(culture);
    }
```

To test it I used the following in MainWindows.xaml.cs

```
 App.SelectCulture("es-ES");
```

the form

```
 <Label Margin="5" Content="{DynamicResource UserID }" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="274"/>
    <TextBox Margin="5" Name="UserIDTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="274" TabIndex="1"/>
    <Label Margin="5" Content="{DynamicResource UserPassword}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="274"/>
    <PasswordBox Margin="5" Name="UserPasswordTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="274" TabIndex="2"/>
    <Button Margin="5" Content="{DynamicResource Login}" Name="loginButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="107" TabIndex="3"/>
    <Label Margin="5" Loaded="TodayLabel_Loaded" Name="TodayLabel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="204"/>
```

The last label display the date, this in the only label that translated other labels are not translated.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to specify "Resources" in the path when you were comparing:

```
// We want our specific culture      
string requestedCulture = string.Format("Resources/StringResources.{0}.xaml", culture);
ResourceDictionary resourceDictionary = dictionaryList.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Source.OriginalString == requestedCulture);
```